# How to import CSV file to Bigtable with multiple column-family names?

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

Trying to import a csv file to a Bigtable table with 2 column-family names:NN and CORR.
[image]

Following this https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-reference#delete_all_rows.

The command that I am executing is 'cbt import knn-item KNN_Items_moviesset.csv'.

I am getting this error message:

[image]

Here is the data to csv file:
[image]

I do not understand the error message since the first column is empty for the row key.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your .csv file format it appears good.

The check that is failing is explicitly looking for an empty string "".

To unblock this you can try commenting out the check and rebuild the tool "go build ."
Code Location https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-bigtable-cbt-cli/blob/2a60a06e181861b7103836b9de5e5305540b15b1/cbt.go#L1863-L1865
(this would involve cloning the repo and using the source if you aren't)

Additionally adding a print for fams[0], or inspecting the .csv for any non visible characters in the first cells could help debug this.